# TypeScript use union of union

Tags: typescript

Can someone please help me understand what is happening here?

```js
type A = { propA: string };
type B = { propB: number }

type U = A | B;

class Model {}

class SingleModel extends Model {

  constructor(input: U) {
    super();
  }
}

class MultiModel extends Model {

  constructor(input: U[]) {
    super();
  }
}

type sheetType = new (input: U | U[]) => Model;

const config: { sheet: sheetType }[] = [
  { sheet: MultiModel },
  { sheet: SingleModel },
];
```

Here I'm getting error: TS: 2322 on `sheet` prop in `config` array. What is wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "transforms to (A | B | U[]), but i need transform to (A | B | A[] | B[])"? U[] is equivalent to A[] | B[] so they are escentially interchangable. Also there is a lot of code there that I am not sure if it has to do with your question or not. I suggest you delete all the code that is not related to the question and put an example of what you're expecting to happen (i.e. a variable assingation that you cannot do but you think you should) so its clearer how the result you're getting is different from what you have

Comment: All the code is related to the question. I'm getting a type error TS: 2322 (on sheet props in configUnion), only having all the above code.

Comment: Is this what you really want? `type sheetTypeUnion = (new (input: U) => Model) | (new (input: U[]) => Model);`

Comment: Yes, but i try to change and got now TS 1386 on second "| (new (input: U[]) => Model)"

Comment: The type `new (input: U | U[]) => Model` means it should happily accept either a `U` or a `U[]` without complaining.  But neither `MultiModel` nor `SingleModel` behave this way, since each one only accepts one of those.  Function/ctor parameters are *contravariant*; by making the input wider you are making the ctor itself narrower.  Look up contravariance and see if that explains it or if you need something else, here.

Comment: That's what I needed:
type sheetType = (new (input: U) => Model) | (new (input: U[]) => Model);

Thanks to everyone, and especially Unmitigated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out the union of the two constructor types separately instead of a single type that would have to accept both `U` and `U[]` as the parameter.

```
type sheetType = (new (input: U) => Model) | (new (input: U[]) => Model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract the two constructor types for readability:

```js
type SingleSheetType = new (input: U) => Model;
type MultiSheetType = new (input: U[]) => Model;

type sheetType = SingleSheetType | MultiSheetType;

const config: { sheet: sheetType }[] = [
  { sheet: MultiModel },
  { sheet: SingleModel },
];
```